# A-star pathfinding algorithm to route through a raster maze

Tags: c++, performance, pathfinding, a-star

I have a problem that needs path finding to solve. It is a vector of ints; 1 for passable terrain and 0 for non-passable. My implementation is not fast enough for the test. How could I make it faster?

```
#include "findpath.h"
#include <algorithm>
struct node
{
    std::pair<int, int> position;
    float length = 0;
    int distance = 0;
    std::vector<int> prevIusSteps;
};
using namespace std;
bool FindPath(std::pair<int, int> Start,
              std::pair<int, int> Target,
              const std::vector<int>& Map,
              std::pair<int, int> MapDimensions,
              std::vector<int>& OutPath)
{
    using namespace std;
bool FindPath(std::pair<int, int> Start,
              std::pair<int, int> Target,
              const std::vector<int>& Map,
              std::pair<int, int> MapDimensions,
              std::vector<int>& OutPath)
{

    bool fundEnd = false;
    deque<node> testQueue;
    node firstNode;

    float tempLength = 0;
    tempLength = abs(Target.first - Start.first) + abs(Target.second - Start.second);
    firstNode = { Start, tempLength * 1.3f, 0, {} };
    testQueue.push_back(firstNode);
    
    vector<int> myMap = Map;

    if (Start == Target)
    {
        return true;
    }

    while (true)
    {

        if (testQueue.size() == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        firstNode = testQueue[0];
        myMap[(firstNode.position.second * MapDimensions.first) + firstNode.position.first] = 0;
 
        testQueue.pop_front();
        if (firstNode.position == Target)
        {
            OutPath = firstNode.prevIusSteps;

            return true;
        }

        addToQueue(testQueue, firstNode, MapDimensions, myMap, 1, 0, Target);
        addToQueue(testQueue, firstNode, MapDimensions, myMap, -1, 0, Target);

        addToQueue(testQueue, firstNode, MapDimensions, myMap, 0, 1, Target);
        addToQueue(testQueue, firstNode, MapDimensions, myMap, 0, -1, Target);
       
    }
    return true;
}

inline void addToQueue(std::deque<node>& testQueue, node firstNode, std::pair<int, int> MapDimensions, const std::vector<int>& Map, int yOffset, int xOffset, std::pair<int, int> Target)
{
    int y = firstNode.position.second + yOffset;
    int x = firstNode.position.first + xOffset;
    int mapIndex = (y * MapDimensions.first) + x;
    if (!isInMap(MapDimensions, x, y))
    {
        return;
    }
    if (Map[mapIndex] == 0)
    {
        return;
    }
   
    float tempLength = 0;
    node tempNode;

    tempNode.position.first = x;
    tempNode.position.second = y;
    tempNode.distance = firstNode.distance + 1;
    tempLength = abs(Target.first - x) + abs(Target.second - y);
    tempNode.length = tempLength * 1.3f;
    tempNode.prevIusSteps = firstNode.prevIusSteps;
    tempNode.prevIusSteps.push_back(mapIndex);
    testQueue.push_back(tempNode);
    std::deque<node>::iterator it = testQueue.begin();


    for (node myNode : testQueue)
    {
        if ((myNode.length + myNode.distance) > (tempNode.distance + tempNode.length))
        {
            testQueue.insert(it, tempNode);
            return;
        }
        it++;
    }
    
}

inline int toIndex(std::pair<int, int> pos, int yOfSet)
{
    return (yOfSet * pos.second +pos.first);
}

inline bool isInMap(std::pair<int, int> MapDimensions, int x, int y)
{
    if (x >= 0 && x < MapDimensions.first) 
    {
        if (y >= 0 && y < MapDimensions.second)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: You have a lot of copy overhead! Why do you make a copy of `Map`. `vector<int> myMap = Map;` That is a lot of overhead if you have a large map. You are also creating copies for no apparent reason in other places `firstNode = testQueue[0];`, `isInMap(std::pair<int, int> MapDimensions`, `std::pair<int, int> pos`, etc...

Comment: @Blindman67 the copying of the map is so that I can edit and add 0 where I have expanded a node. The other stuff is fair and I will try to change them and see if it helps. Thank you. If you have any other ideas, please comment and I appreciate all the feedback even if it’s harsh.

Comment: Adding nodes to the stack (deque) is too complex. You copy the vector of previous indexes for every node to get the path back to start `OutPath = firstNode.prevIusStep` when you reach the target. Rather stack the index and store distance in an array (`distmap[index] = distance`). When you reach target search the `distmap` back to start by following the lowest values. This adds overhead at the end but saves the huge overhead of creating a path for every step searched forward.

Comment: @Blindman67 I removed deque and    made it a vector. And now I store the path with indexing pointing to the previous step. Du you think you’re way is faster?

Comment: Depends on how you implement it. It will help if you performance test your code to compare versions. This will help you gain an insight and intuition  on how changes impact performance.